# How to resolve this error: "Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables" for Always Encrypted feature enabled in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, always-encrypted

I am getting below exception when I try to run the application from visual studio 2019.
I am fetching data through Entity framework form SQL server 2019. I have made all necessary configurations to enable always encrypted in respective DB and modified connection string with `column encryption setting = Enabled`

> Inner Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables 'Column Name'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'AEForCEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DBName') and the expression near line '14' expects it to be PLAINTEXT

As per the sources I have enabled parameterization in SSMS query window and run below simple query, I am able to get the result as expected. but how to enable this when I am getting data through entity framework in my C# Application.

```
declare @email nvarchar(100) = 'head@headoffice.com'
    select * FROM [DBNAme].[dbo].[TableName] where email= @email
```

In the above query email column is encrypted with deterministic type

My C# code is:

```
using (var context = new MyDBContext())
{
    var totalRecordCount = context.Offices.Where(x => x.isDeleted == false).Count();
    if (totalRecordCount == 0)
        return new List<UserOffice>();
    var offices = context.Offices.Where(x => x.isDeleted == false);
    return offices.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without proper code details, it's quite tough to understand. Though, try this

```
using (var context = new YourDbContext())
{
    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
    // Your query logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the suggestion did not work. My code is simple as below. using (var context = new MyDBContext()) { var totalRecordCount = context.Offices.Where(x => x.isDeleted == false).Count(); if (totalRecordCount == 0) return new List<UserOffice>(); var offices = context.Offices.Where(x => x.isDeleted == false); return offices.ToList(); }